# ExtJS Portal - Columns of different sizes

Tags: extjs, portal

I need to be able to use different size columns in the ExtJS portal.  For example, I want in the center region, one area which has room for one big widget, and then right below it, 2 areas for 2 smaller widgets.  I keep trying to play with the columns to figure this out, but nothing seems to work.  Help?

Answer (score 1):

The portal uses a `ColumnLayout`, so you should be able to configure column widths as needed using standard configs.  What have you tried (i.e., post some code)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far:

```
var portalColumns =
    [{
        columnWidth: .70,
        id: 'firstColumn',
        style: 'padding:10px 0 10px 10px'
    }, {
        columnWidth: .30,
        id: 'secondColumn',
        style: 'padding:10px 0 10px 10px'
    }];

    var mainPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        renderTo: 'pnlContent',
        layout: 'border',
        height: 730,
        width: 1255,
        id: 'mainPanel',
        items: [portalNavigation,
        {
        xtype: 'portal',
        region: 'center',
        margins: '35 5 5 0',
        items: [portalColumns ]
        }]
    });
```

I know I can configure the column widths for the entire portal, but I need them to be stacked.  So one column on top which spans the entire width, and then two below it which is composed of two individual widths.  If I have to express it in HTML, here it is:

table
tr td colspan="2" tr
tr td td tr
table

Answer (score 0):

if i get this right a tableLayout would be more fitting your needs ...
give it a try : http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.layout.TableLayout